# RLMResults' does not have a member named 'Generator

Tags: swift, realm

http://qiita.com/jtemplej/items/1c1b7204341ac01e561e

上記のサイトを参考に`Realm`を使い始めたのですが、`for realmBook in Book.allObjects()`の行で`'RLMResults' does not have a member named 'Generator'`というエラーが表示されます。何か初歩的なことが間違っているような気がするのですが、どこが間違っているのでしょうか？下記に現在のコードを記しますので、どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Book.swift

```
import Foundation
import Realm

class Book : RLMObject {
    dynamic var isbn = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var price = 0
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Realm

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        stockData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func stockData() {
        let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

        // Bookオブジェクト生成.
        let book = Book()
        book.isbn = "999999"
        book.name = "realm sample"
        book.price = 100

        // Bookオブジェクトを保存.
        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        realm.addObject(book)
        realm.commitWriteTransaction()

        // 先ほどのBookオブジェクトを取得
        // Class.allObjectsで全オブジェクト取得.
        for realmBook in Book.allObjects() {
            // book name:realm sample
            println("book name:\((realmBook as Book).name)")
        }

        let book2 = Book()
        book2.isbn = "999998"
        book2.name = "realm tutorial 1"
        book2.price = 1000

        // Blockでの保存の仕方.
        realm.transactionWithBlock() {
            realm.addObject(book2)
        }

        for realmBook in Book.allObjects() {
            // book name:realm sample
            // book name:realm tutorial 1
            println("book name:\((realmBook as Book).name)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ここを見る限りでは「RLMSupport.swift」というファイルが必要なようですが入っていますか？

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1487

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。「RLMSupport.swift」をプロジェクトに追加すると質問にあるエラー文を消すことができました！しかし今度は「RLMSupport.swift」のimport Realm の行で「No such module 'Realm'」というエラーが表示されました。。。

Comment: 「RLMSupp‌​ort.swift」のimport Realmの行を削除することで動作させることができました！誠にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

`import Realm`してないからじゃないですか？Realmフレームワークを使っているswiftファイルは、すべてimportしてみましょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ViewController.swiftでimport Realmを追記したのですが、No Such Module 'Realm'と表示されました。もちろんCocoaPodでRealmはインストールしてあり、Link Binary With LibrariesにlibPods-Realm.aを追加しています。また、TestRealm-Bridging-Header.hというファイルを作成し、ファイル内に#import <Realm/Realm.h>と記述しています。